# Checking if "Hyperlink or Picture" column is empty in sharepoint flow

Tags: hyperlink, flow

I have a Hyperlink or Picture column in sharepoint online list named "Document Link" I am creating a flow where I need to check a condition if this column is empty or null.
I have tried few things but while using Get Items action the action is not giving result DocumentLink=null if it is empty. It is gives the values if it is not null and hence I am not able to check the empty condition against it.

Comment: edited my answer, try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use HTTP request to SharePoint and use API GET. [Documentation here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest), it will give you NULL values. Include column in Select property, like [here](https://www.chakkaradeep.com/2018/05/16/working-with-the-sharepoint-send-http-request-flow-action/).

Like this:
[image]

it will return JSON collection with null values too (see in next picture) of Items (or if you use item(id) in HTTP request URI > return only 1 item)

[image]

after this you just need Parse JSON action and after this work with the properties from it.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Hi Zdeněk Vinduška . It worked . Thanks:)

Comment: you're welcome :)